# Listing certain contents from a site in the terminal

Tags: command-line, websites, lynx

This was one of the 12 problems in my practical exam today . For the first part of the task,  we were supposed to list the contents of the first page from http://slashdot.org . I used lynx for this one. Then, for the second part, we were asked to filter the output in such a way to only list the headlines ( article names) from the first page of slashdot.org ( this one literally crushed me) .
Bear in mind that this was a task out of 12 in an 100 minute exam,  so I reckon there's a fast way to do it, but I couldn't manage to find a discernable patteren . Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '<h.*>.*<\/h.>' sample.html | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

grep 'regex(all heading tags)' filename pipe(" | ") sed remove all html tags

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need two components. First you need something that can fetch the slashdot main page (the raw html), and then something that lets you get the headlines from that.

The first component could be `curl` or `wget`. I'm partial to `wget`:

wget -O slashdot.html http://slashdot.org

Next, look at slashdot.html with a text editor. You'll find that headlines are contained in  tags. So the second component is something that understands HTML well enough to let you get only the h2 tags. You could do this with some clever regular expressions using grep, awk or sed but you'll go insane. I prefer something that knows HTML a bit better. If you're allowed to install extra packages, get the `libxml2-utils` package and use `xmllint`. It can parse HTML (with the -html switch) and understands xpath notation for HTML/XML node selection. Explaining xpath is beyond the scope of an answer here, and it would make a very good research topic for you to learn more, so I suggest you google "xpath" to understand how it works.

About the only additional trick is that xmllint will print the text from h2 nodes verbatim, so it will look ugly as they're all in one line. I'll also use redirection and pipes to avoid creating temporary files, and discarding xmllint's html validation output (slashdot html is terribly noncompliant):

```
wget -q -O - http://slashdot.org | xmllint -html -xpath '//h2/span/a/text()' - 2>/dev/null
```

You'll notice it shows the headlines all in one line. Now, to separate them, change it to this (to insert a `\n` character as part of headline text, before the closing `</a>`:

```
wget -q -O - http://slashdot.org | sed 's/<\/a>/\n<\/a>/g' | xmllint -html -xpath '//h2/span/a/text()' - 2>/dev/null
```

1. First, wget the slashdot homepage, outputting the HTML to standard output (`-O -`), and suppressing wget progress messages (`-q`).
2. Pipe this to sed to add `\n` after each closing `</a>` tag.
3. Finally pipe this to xmllint (use `-` as input file to read from stdin), ask it to use the html parser and show only nodes matching the given xpath expression, discarding any diagnostic output (`2>/dev/null` to discard standard error).